# How do I constrain the width of a html element to the content of said element?

Tags: html, css

I've got a heading that I want to size according to the contents within. Not dynamically, just for the one heading.

Edit: what follows has no impact on the question (but people moan about all sorts of nonsense)

```css
h1 {
  margin: auto auto 10px 10px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  border-bottom: 4px outset #227777;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px black;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code...

Comment: you have to share your current code that you are using, we have to see and test it!

Comment: Do you have your html?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some code to your question, so we can better understand your question and possibly identify the issue(s). Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before adding your code.

Comment: Nothing tried, nothing to show us ? This is not a do-my-job site.

Comment: @Scath: I can't imagine the markup being much more complex than a simple h1 or h2 element.

Comment: @Julien: Sizing a single HTML element is hardly "doing someone's job". No need for the attitude.

Comment: @BoltClock with nothing shown nor tried, it unfortunately is :-/

Comment: @Sinto I do have code, thing is, this question is relatively trivial and straightforward. I just didn't have the time to mull this over, it's more for interest's sake. So I thought: "Hey why not ask someone real quick while I move on with the back-end, since this holds no real impact towards actually getting the job done." But now I've spent this time typing out this lengthy tirade. Sorry if this in any measure comes off as offensive, that is not my intent.

Comment: @Sinto In fact, this was also posted to feel out the waters on this site. I don't usually involve myself, and I thought it might be good to get more involved. But if this is the response to a basic question I wonder what a total beginner feels like to be callously dismissed when they're simply trying to figure something out.

Comment: @Julien The point was, it's not really even directly involved with my code but the language itself. How does knowing my code factor into a trivially solved issue like this? It's not like I'm trying to make a dynamically responsive element that needs to take many different values. Look I'm trying not to step on people's toes but I'll pose the same scenario; if I was learning the language. No prior knowledge, no code, no idea of where to start. How would a response like yours help someone like that. Code is strongly suggested, not obligated. Or I wouldn't have been allowed to post this.

Comment: @Julien Thank you. Representative of the community. *Genuine sarcasm* This became unnecessarily unprofessional. A simple question, no matter how trivial, don't deserve dismissals just because it did not fulfill your list of requirements. If I was a novice with no code it would still have been a valid question.

Comment: I haven't even had this account for a day and I already wonder why I made it. If someone had asked me, in real life, the question I posed without code to show for it. I would still have attempted to help them, because why not. If the code was compulsory then the site would have blocked me from posting my question without it. Well it has code now, not that it makes a bit of difference! Thanks for a wasted half hour on trivialities. I'm surprisingly angry about this, I always try to help however I can. Done. Goodbye.

Comment: @ReenenVorster keep doing like this and unconsider the -11 vote ;)

Comment: @Julien Clarify. You phrasing can be taken in two tones; by "unconcider", which isn't a word, did you mean disregard?

Comment: @ReenenVorster it was in a sense of "ignoring them", not "disregarding them"

Comment: @Julien Thanks. Sorry if I came across as vitriolic. Have a nice day.

Comment: @ReenenVorster No problem, it's also part of the game.

Comment: @ReenenVorster: Its great to go trough your words. As I know, here we have to ask some doubts regarding the codes that we have did or we are struggling to recover. If you do not have time & not interested to share what you did its not helpful to other. Stack does not wish solve your own problems, it consider others also. Some time your question might be valuable valid & will help other. You have give time to it. Even I'm thought like this 'its common question or it might not require explanation, etcc.. etc... '. You have to show some effect on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're saying that you only want the H1 element to be as wide as the text within it. If that's the case, you need to set `display: inline;`.

```css
h1 {
  margin: auto auto 10px 10px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  border-bottom: 4px outset #227777;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px black;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1>Heading</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Inline-block would be more appropriate because many styles do not apply to inline elements.